# RedirectMatch 301 Removing URL Parameters

Tags: apache, url, redirect

I have a file `.conf` in my server apache with the redirects and I want to redirect a url with parameters. An example is this:

```
https://example.com/presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso?PageSpeed=noscript
```

I need to redirect this to the same page, as in the example below:

```
https://example.com/presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso
```

In my `.conf` file, I try the following code without success:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso$ /presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso?
```

I can not use redirects from `.htaccess` nor the Apache `RewriteRule` method.Even researching, researching and trying, so far nothing has worked out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not redirect a URL with `query string` using `Redirect` directive as it doesn't match against `?PageSpeed=noscript` . You need to use `Mod-rewrite` .

Assuming `mod-rewrite` module is enabled on your server , you can use something like the following in your Apache config or htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso/?$ /presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It did not work ... I'm forced to do the redirect from `Mod-rewrite` and so, can not I do from `RedirectMatch`?

Comment: @MatheusPortela `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` both directives are part of `mod-alias` (alias module) on apache server. You can't use them to test query string . Isnt the above working for you?

Comment: No, unfortunately it did not work. I tested the .conf and .htaccess file as well and nothing worked. I restarted apache, in addition to the modules are active, however it did not work.

Comment: @MatheusPortela if you are going to `https://example.com/presente/decoracao/teu-sorriso?PageSpeed=noscript` URL then this rule should work. I have already tested this on my server it works fine.  Try clearing your browser cache .

Comment: I cleaned the browser cache and cookies, but still it still does not work, as well as restarting apache and varnish. The above code I inserted into my server's .htaccess file inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`.

Comment: @MatheusPortela It looks like your server isnt reading your htaccess file. Are you sure `AllowOverride` is set to `all` in your config file?

Comment: In the httpd.conf file on my server, `AllowOverride` is set to `all` for sure, because in that same file I have other important redirects that work normally. But, especially this one, it does not work ... Would there be any factor with respect to `Apache` that is blocking it?

Comment: @MatheusPortela what url are you going to and what happens when the http request finishes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191984/discussion-between-starkeen-and-matheus-portela).

Comment: It worked! The problem that was making the redirect not work was the location from which I was inserting the code into my `.htaccess` file.